# QlikView: generic report based on dynamic table structure

Tags: qlikview

I have to display tabular data whose structure (columns and headers) changes depending on an ID. For ID "A" I would get columns "Name|Address|valid" but for ID "B" I would get "Name|Birthday|Sex|".

The dynamic structure would be implemented by a stored procedure that returns different tables based on the ID.

**Is it possible to create a generic report based on this?**

In the report I would like to be able to filter based on the columns like one is used to from Excel. Also the headers of the columns would be dynamic ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Qlikview 11, you can use conditional show/hide for each dimension/expression in charts.

Use an expression like

```
GetFieldSelections(ID) = 'A'
```

in the condition section of the chart properties for the other dimensions

[image: Chart Properties]

If you are using QLikSense, you can do this through the API but it seems it breaks the purpose of QlikSense (which is pure adhoc discovery as compared to guided analytics of Qlikview 11).

If you are using Qlikview 10, you can do this by saving the expression in a variable and calling the variable in the dimension of your chart.